# Удаление элементов списка во время итерации

Tags: java, алгоритм

Необходимо удалить элементы из списка по некоторому условие, которое зависит от того, какие элементы в списке уже есть. То есть, что необходимо

```
for (Element element : list) {
    list.removeIf(e -> e.isRelative(element));
}
```

То есть, нужно удалить элементы, которые по какому-то условию общие. После удаления элемента необходимо продолжить удаление элементов с уже отфильтрованной коллекции.

Задача напоминает задачу об удалении дубликатов. Получаем элемент, удаляем дубликаты из коллекции, продолжаем итерацию по отредактированной коллекции.

Все бы хорошо, но редактирование коллекции во время итерации запрещено. Значит нужен какой-то способ через временные коллекции

Есть варианты как это сделать?

Comment: @Kromster эм. В том, что джава запрещает редактирование коллекций во время итерации?

Comment: Хорошо бы понимать, что именно делает метод `isRelative` и какой смысл кода в целом. Даже если вы решите проблему с модификацией коллекции, у вас квадратичный алгоритм, который не редко служит признаком ошибочного подхода к задаче.

Comment: мне кажется поможет свертка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = list.size() - 1; j > i; j--)
            if (list.get(i).isRelative(list.get(j)))
                list.remove(j);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для удаления элементов из итерирруемой коллекции всегда можно использовать старый добрый Iterator

```
Iterator<Element> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Element e = iterator.next();
    if (isNeedRemove(e)) { //тут вы как-то понимаете что элемент нужно удалить
       iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Правильно, но поблемма именно удаления элемента по некому условию схожести элементов. Как я привел пример с дубликатами. Нужно удалить элементы, если хотя бы один такой уже есть в коллекции. Потому получается, что я не могу вызвать метод isNeedRemove(e), ему неоткуда взяться

Comment: Вы хотите проверить, есть ли аналогичный элемент коллекции? Тогда либо определяйте метод equals у Ваших объектов в коллекции, который сможет однозначно сказать, что элементы идентичны. Тогда достаточно будет положить List в Set и java сама уберет одиннаковые элементы.

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko так и не смог понять, что вы хотите. В вопросе вы акцентируете внимание на том, что у вас не получается удалить элемент из коллекции при ее итерировании, а теперь говорите, что нужно удалить дубликаты. Про удаление дубликатов достаточно информации в интернете. Один из самых популярных - создать вторую коллекцию и добавлять туда элементы из старой коллекции, при этом предварительно вызывая метод `contains`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko подобие дубликатов. Между элементами есть связь и нужно оставить только один элемент из группы. Оказалось, что сложнее объяснить сам вопрос, чем самому решить)

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko теперь стало понятно) Ну что сказать, единственное, что мне приходит в голову - создать дополнительную коллекцию такого же типа, идти по элементам исходной коллекции и внутри этого прохода будет еще один проход по дополнительной коллекции с проверкой каждого элемента доп. коллекции на ваше условие. Получается не очень эффективно (Сложность стремится к O(n^2) ).

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (condition) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

а так? :)

Comment: Сам подход верный, но у автора главная проблема связана c условием. У него не просто метод, а метод экземпляра, тобишь `element.condition(otherElement)`.

Comment: Ну, условие что в итераторе что в таком цикле будет строиться одинаково. В этом цикле мы всегда можем получить Element element = list.get(i). А уж конкретика условия (а соответственно, возможность такого подхода) - это на усмотрение автора вопроса

Comment: Я долго пытался понять как оно должно работать) Не очевидное, но оригинальное решение. Пришел к чему-то похожему, но с созданием нового списка и множества ручных операций

Comment: Хотя нет. Надо правку откатить. В моем случае работает, но потом обязательно за пределы массива вылезет)

Comment: Правку я откатил. Просто недавно на стеке и пока слегка путаюсь... А вылезать за пределы массива не должно. Если только условие не обращается к элементу (i-1). Но эти "краевые эффекты" в любом случае вручную ловить нужно...